# Design of NO SQL Database

Tags: database-design, azure, nosql, azure-table-storage

As a training project I am trying to build a Family tree application on Azure.

The first step is the database, I plan to use table storage.

What would a table storage design look like for a Family tree application?

I have though of a couple of solutions.

- one entry per person, with xml with all relationships for that person. But that would mean updating several rows for a given change and a lot of duplicate data.
- one table for each type of information, one for persons, one for relationships... But this just feels like a relational database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a partition per family with a row per person, so for each person the partition key would be the family and the row key the identifier for the person. On each person put an attribute for the parents (normally just two :)). This way you can quickly read the entire partition into memory and traverse the graph using an in memory tree structure. A typical family should have less than a hundred nodes, so would be lightning fast. Updates would always be to a family, so transactions can be used as each family is in a partition.

For a really difficult (related) exercise, implement a graph database (like your family tree) on top of a key-value store (table storage). Think of the problem that twitter or facebook have where you need to see updates (tweets, news) across all relationships (social graph). You then start getting into the interesting (hard) parts of NoSQL.

Answer (score 1):

My first question would be how do you plan to access the information? Think about structuring the data how you need to access it. Don't shy away from breaking the rules of normalization we've been fed for the last 20 years. Embrace redundant specialized models. Also think out of the box and consider the use of parrallel queries. if the data is stored in several locations, go after each location simultaneously and aggregate the results.

And lastly, store some data in the predefined display format. Odds are your family tree info is mostly read, so have "views" that are optimized. Maybe when you find the person you want to display, there's a single XML file there that gives all that data ready to view.

Answer (score 1):

Given that a family tree application has more to do with relationships between entities than the entities themselves, modeling this in a relational database would be the better fit.

I release this does not answer your question, but at the end of the day we need to choose the most appropriate tool for the task.